# How to change Drag shadow after drag has been started in android?

Tags: android, drag

I want to change the image of the dragShadow after startDrag has been called.
but i don't find any API that can be do that.
any suggestion how can I do that?

```
            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) v.getTag());
            String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
            ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);
            View.DragShadowBuilder dragShadow= new View.DragShadowBuilder(((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.rele_button)));
```

Comment: overide View.DragShadowBuilder class and use. You may find a sample code in [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

Comment: I saw before and I tried but I can't chagne it.

Comment: please post more code

Answer (score 0):

more code 
code of Class that extend View.DragShadowBuilder

```
public class ImageDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {
private static Drawable shadow;

ImageDragShadowBuilder() {
    super();
}

public static View.DragShadowBuilder fromResource(Context context, int drawableId) {
    ImageDragShadowBuilder builder = new ImageDragShadowBuilder();

    builder.shadow = context.getResources().getDrawable(drawableId);
    if (builder.shadow == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Drawable from id is null");
    }

    builder.shadow.setBounds(0, 0, builder.shadow.getMinimumWidth(), builder.shadow.getMinimumHeight());

    return builder;
}

public static View.DragShadowBuilder fromBitmap(Context context, Bitmap bmp) {
    if (bmp == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bitmap cannot be null");
    }

    ImageDragShadowBuilder builder = new ImageDragShadowBuilder();

    builder.shadow = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp);
    builder.shadow.setBounds(0, 0, builder.shadow.getMinimumWidth(), builder.shadow.getMinimumHeight());

    return builder;
}

@Override
public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
    shadow.draw(canvas);
}

@Override
public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint) {
    shadowSize.x = shadow.getMinimumWidth();
    shadowSize.y = shadow.getMinimumHeight();

    shadowTouchPoint.x = (int)(shadowSize.x / 2);
    shadowTouchPoint.y = (int)(shadowSize.y / 2);
}
```

}

code for change after start drag is called

this code belong to onDrag function

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    ImageDragShadowBuilder.fromResource(getBaseContext(), R.mipmap.phone_icon);
```